# Failed to add the foreign key constraint 2

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE Program(
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    abbreviation VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
    ssn INTEGER CHECK (ssn > 0) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    login VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    program VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ssn),
    FOREIGN KEY (program) REFERENCES Program(name),
    UNIQUE (login),
    UNIQUE (ssn, program)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Branch(
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    program VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name),
    FOREIGN KEY (program) REFERENCES Program(name)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE BelongsTo(
    student INTEGER NOT NULL,
    branch VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    program VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (student, program) REFERENCES Student(ssn, program),
    FOREIGN KEY (branch, program) REFERENCES Branch(name, program)
);
```

Program, Student, Branch got successfully created. But while creating BelongsTo sql throws:

> Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'belongsto_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'branch'

Also, I need to design schema as per: http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2018/course/TDA357/VT2018/lab/task1.txt

Please feel free to ask me about more details regarding this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: The PK of `Branch` is `name`, not `name, program`. You can probably add a unique key like you also did for `student`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `program` for the branch foreign key or for the `student` foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE BelongsTo(
    student INTEGER NOT NULL,
    branch VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    program VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (student, program) REFERENCES Student(ssn),
    FOREIGN KEY (branch) REFERENCES Branch(name)
);
```

Note:  The `student` foreign key definition works because you have a redundant unique constraint on `student(ssn, program)`.  The column `ssn` is already unique, because it is the primary key, so program is always unique per student too (because there is only one of them).

Comment: please have a look at [link](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2018/course/TDA357/VT2018/lab/task1.txt), we are asked to design schema as per given instructions. Although your answer seems to be correct. Thanks.